# Taskbar buttons combining in Windows 10

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-10, taskbar, shortcuts

Is it possible to get Windows Explorer in Windows 10 to do the following:
I want to have to Windows Explorer shortcuts in the taskbar - Windows explorer and Downloads folder. That is easily done as can be seen in the screenshot.

[image: Taskbar two Windows Explorer icons]

Paths are as follows.

[image: Windows Explorer path]
[image: Downloads path]

The issue I'm having is that when I click on Downloads shortcut, it does open Downloads folder but highlights Explorer icon.

[image: Windows Explorer icon highlighted when Downloads folder open]

I could get it to work in Windows 7 without any problems at all.

These are my settings for Windows taskbar, 7+ Taskbar Tweaker, Ultimate Windows Tweaker 4.

[image: Taskbar settings] 
[image: 7+ Taskbar Tweaker]
[image: Ultimate Windows Tweaker]

To make it clear, I want Downloads shortcut to be highlighted when Downloads shortcut is clicked and Explorer icon highlighted only when I click on Explorer, not when I click on Downloads.

Comment: Maybe that old W7 software does not work properly in Windows 10.

Comment: Both of those are optimized for Windows 10 and I don't believe I used any of these in Windows 7.